# Read from the file and add to map interface java

Tags: java, dictionary, io, bufferedreader

I have a text file with such stuff inside, and I need to skip all with #:

```
###########################################################################
#Copyright 1999 The Internet Dictionary Project/Tyler Chambers
#http://www.june29.com/IDP/
#This file is free to use and modify.  Thank you for using the IDP.
#
#Approximately 5048 entries.  9/21/97
#Approximately 5488 entries.  1/7/98
#Approximately 5910 entries.  3/8/98
#Approximately 7450 entries.  2/19/99
###########################################################################
a   un, uno, una[Article]
aardvark    cerdo hormiguero
aardvark    oso hormiguero[Noun]
aardvarks   cerdos hormigueros
aardvarks   osos hormigueros 
ab  prefijo que indica separacio/n
aback   hacia atras
aback   hacia atrás,take aback, desconcertar. En facha.
aback   por sopresa, desprevenidamente, de improviso
aback   atra/s[Adverb]
abacterial  abacteriano, sin bacterias
```

I need to create a map>
where key is String english it is a first word in text file
and List it is all spanish words in line with the eng key word

I have something like this, but it shows NullPointerException this line: 
try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/Spanish.txt"))))

Maybe because i have wrong "if (!line.startsWith("#"))"??

```
try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/Spanish.txt"))))
    {
            Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();

            String eng;
            List<String> spn = null;

            while (in.readLine() != null){

            String line = in.readLine();
                if (!line.startsWith("#")){
                    String[] parts = line.split(" ");
                    eng = parts[0];
                    for (int i = 1; i < parts.length; i++){
                        spn.add(parts[i]);
                    }
                    map.put(eng, spn);
                }    

            }

            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found!");
        }
```

Comment: Which line throws the NPE?

Comment: `List<String> spn = null;` instantiate it so it's not `null`.. You probably want to do this inside the `while` block.